# Normalized HeatMap Across Shapefiles

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I will try to explain what I want to achieve.

Consider that we have 2 shapefiles: A.shp and B.shp

A.shp contains 100 points and in the circle at point (0,0) with radius 5 there are 10 points

B.shp contains 10 points and in the circle at point (0,0) with radius 5 there is 1 point
If I run the heatmap plugin, at the point (0,0) the color created would be the same.

Is it possible to normalize the heatmap across shapefiles to take into consideration the quantity of the points across the files?